# MySQL GROUP BY with substring not looping through

Tags: mysql, group-by, substring

I am trying to group by a substring.  I only get the one result:

```
Region = Coastal, Value (R) = 1144900.
```

I am supposed to get 2 results.

This is my code:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`team_name`, '-', 1) AS 'Region', 
  SUM(`opportunities`.`value`) AS 'Value (R)'
FROM 
  `opportunities` 
  LEFT JOIN cf_type_link_data ON cf_type_link_data.sourceid = opportunities.id
  LEFT JOIN cf_lu_type_fields ON cf_type_link_data.fieldid = cf_lu_type_fields.id
  LEFT JOIN cf_lu_types_fields_dropdown ON cf_type_link_data.`value` = cf_lu_types_fields_dropdown.id AND cf_lu_type_fields.id = cf_lu_types_fields_dropdown.fieldid
  LEFT JOIN `lu_teams` ON `lu_teams`.`contactid` = `opportunities`.`user_allocation`
  LEFT JOIN `teams` ON `teams`.`id` = `lu_teams`.`teamid`
  LEFT JOIN `lu_opportunity_status` ON `lu_opportunity_status`.`id` = `opportunities`.`status`
WHERE 1 
  AND `cf_lu_types_fields_dropdown`.`values` = 'Building Project'
  AND cf_lu_type_fields.fieldname = 'Scaffolding Segment'
  AND (`opportunities`.`expecteddate` >= '2012-01-01' AND `opportunities`.`expecteddate` <= '2012-07-24')
GROUP BY 'Region' 
ORDER BY cf_lu_types_fields_dropdown.`values`;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We need to see an example of your table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use same alias from select in `GROUP BY` clause

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(team_name, '-', 1) AS 'Region', 
       SUM(opportunities.value) AS 'Value (R)'....

GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(team_name, '-', 1)
ORDER BY cf_lu_types_fields_dropdown.values;
```

Comment: Yes you can, MySQL permits it, unlike SQL Server.

Comment: I get two results but now the problem is that in Coastal which is one of the results, there are supposed 2 results in coastal (value is 903400 but it should be 1144900 because it is missing the other result) but it is only getting 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use quotes for field identifiers -

'Region' -> Region

In your case you see only one record in result data set because you group by string 'Region', but you should group by value(s).

Comment: I am still getting 1 result if I group by value(s).

Comment: Then your query returns ONE value. Check this values - `SUBSTRING_INDEX(`team_name`, '-', 1)`, check WHERE conditions.

Comment: I know it returns 2 values.  because I can see the results.  The above answer works except that the there are multiple results within each of the 2 results but it is only returning 1.

Comment: Can you show your edited query? If `SUBSTRING_INDEX(`team_name`, '-', 1)` returns two different values and WHERE filter is correct, then you have to get 2 records as you expect. Check if everything is correct.